# Keep text formatting in SQL

Tags: sql, formatting

I have a text area that inserts its content into a SQL table. Is there a way to keep the formatting of the text and then use it in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean keep the Enters then replace the char 10 and char 13 with <br/>

When using SQL (note the enters)

```
select replace(' 
test
test','
','<br/>')
```

This results in `<br/>test<br/>test`

Comment: Added the SQL code in the answer. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Or in VB >> textbox.Text = Value.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br/>")

Comment: What is value supposed to be?

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you're talking about preserving line breaks.

Either:

Output the text inside a <pre> tag

or

Convert newlines to <br /> tags before insertion to the DB.  (E.g. nl2br in PHP).

Comment: Thank you. The pre tag worked perfectly and allowed me to style the text very easily.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to paragraph the text? Text seems to keep going on the same line if there are no manual line breaks.

Comment: You'll need to add extra breaks (word_wrap in PHP) and/or use CSS (set a max width and the overlow attribute)

Comment: Set overflow to what exactly?

Comment: The text is still going outside the layout.

Comment: Have you performed some operation to limit the max line length alà word_wrap?
Have you used CSS to style the element as suggested (e.g. max-width: 52em; overflow:scroll;) ?

Answer (score 1):

Text is text is text. Insert the text into the table including its markup and it will come out that way as well.

...or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @BioXhazard Then you're looking for @rdkleine's or @Pete's answer.